# creating a constant vector of variable width in verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm writing some synthesizable Verilog. I need to create a value to use as a mask in a larger expression. This value is a sequence of 1's, when the length is stored in some register:

```
buffer & {offset{1'h1}};
```

where `buffer` and `offset` are both registers. What I expect is for `buffer` to be `and`ed with `11111...` of width `offset`. However, the compiler says this illegal in verilog, since `offset` needs to be constant.

Instead, I wrote the following:

```
buffer & ~({WIDTH{1'h1}} << offset)
```

where `WIDTH` is a constant. This works. Both expressions are equivalent in terms of values, but obviously not in terms of the hardware that would be synthesized.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is because of the rules for context-determined expressions (detailed in sections 11.6 and 11.8 of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM) require the width of all operands of an expression be known at compile time.

Your example is too simple to show where the complication arises, but let's say `buffer` was 16-bit signed variable. To perform bitwise-and (`&`), you first need to know size of both operands, then extend the smaller operand to match the size of the larger operand. If we don't know what the size of `{offset{1'h1}}` is, we don't know whether it needs to 0-extended, or `buffer` needs to be sign-extended.

Of course, the language could be defined to allow this so it works, but synthesis tools would be creating a lot of unnecessary additional hardware. And if we start applying this to more complex expressions, trying to determine how the bit-widths propagate becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

Both parts of your question impliy the `replication` operator. The operator requires you to use a `replication constant` to show how many times to replicate. So, the first part of your example **is** illegal. The `offset` must be a constant, not a reg.

Also, the constant is not a width of something, but a number of times the `{1}` is repeated. So, the second  part of the example is correct syntactically.

Comment: Semantically, note that in the second part, buffer is anded with a negation of a shift. so, if start with '1111' and left shift it, i get, say, '11100', then negation - '00011', which is what I needed - a sequence of ones. 

I guess answer to my question is "because the language standard says so". But I'm looking for a deeper engineering reason for such a decision.

Comment: sorry, i missed the negation part.